# Creating simple meshes programatically on three.js

Tags: javascript, html, mesh, three.js

How to create simple meshes like ramps, cones, revolution shapes, just by giving their vertexes, on three.js?

Answer (score 2):

That should help:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/255